# What does a brown squiggle from Words spelling/grammar checker signify?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

This is something I've never seen before, so I'm not sure what Word thinks is wrong.  Its suggestions look like the randomish stuff I'd expect from a word not in the dictionary, but that would be a red underline.  The standard complaint about contractions would be green, so that's not it either.

The sentence in question is:

> My calendar is more or less free all day, so feel free to call whenever’s good for you.

The underline is on whenever's

Comment: What's underlined? A screenshot would help here.

Comment: Right-clicking on the underlined word should give you more information.

Comment: @KeithThompson it gave a list of alternate words like a spelling error; it did not give the concurrent grammar suggestion (whenever is) which left me wondering why it was colored the way it was and if it was trying to indicate a different class of problem.  The lack of a real spelling error compounded my confusion about why it was suggesting seemingly random words.  (Editing "whenever is" to "whenever's" will only show the grammar error until the cursor leaves the word; at which point the underline goes from green to brown and only the spelling error is shown.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently, it means there is both a spelling and grammar error](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_brown_underline_under_a_word_mean_in_Microsoft_Word)

It might have something to do with the word `whenever's` since Firefox is picking that up as misspelled.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, most words with a contraction attached trigger the spell checker.  Is detaching standard contraction suffixes and doing spell/grammar checks on the expanded form really that hard? /Soapbox